# Method links does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There are several people who have the same problem. So, the problem is related to pagination?

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

```
public function index()
{
    $garages = Garage::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
     return view('admin.garages.index', compact('garages'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not `paginate` your query, try with this:

```php
public function index()
{
    $garages = Garage::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);
     return view('admin.garages.index', compact('garages'));
}
```

The `get()` function returns a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections), the `paginate()` function returns a [Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) that has the `links()` function you want.

Comment: Thank you dparoli,  I understand now.